# How to read sk_buff data if we have have sock structure of specific process?

Tags: c, sockets, process, linux-kernel, udp

I have written a program where I can access the sock struct of the specific process but want to read sport and dport by reading sk_buff. But, I am unable to access sk_buff from the sock struct. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: If you have a pointer to the `struct sock`, can't you just access `sock_ptr->sk_dport`? I didn't find `sport` in neither `struct sock` nor `struct sk_buff` though.

Answer (score 0):

If `buf` is a `struct sk_buff*`, then its source and destination ports are

```c
buf->sk->sk_num
buf->sk->sk_dport
```

respectively.

This works since `struct sk_buff` [contains a pointer](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/include/linux/skbuff.h#L773) to a `struct sock`, which [defines a few macros](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/include/net/sock.h#L373) to allow easy access to the port numbers you're looking for.

Comment: Why in dport am I always getting 0 if sk_dport always prints dport?

Comment: I'm not sure. You might need to include a [reprex] in your question to get further help.